# How to know react app is open in web or mobile app

Tags: ios, reactjs, npm

I have react web application and an IOS app(web view). I want to add some extra functionality to the IOS app. Is there any way I can determine whether the app is open on the web or mobile?

Comment: add some extra information about ur problem and whether it is react app or react native app. react app is supported for only webview and react native app is supported to mobiles like android and ios.

Comment: @SujithKumar is react app. also, I have a native IOS app in which the web view is showing

Comment: you can add google analytics in your code.. they have good dashboard too..

Comment: Can you explain more about your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you should use [deeplink](https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97) and check

```
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
            if let url = launchOptions?[.url] as? URL {
                // TODO: handle URL from here
            }
    
            return true
        }
    
        func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    
            // TODO: handle URL from here
    
            return true
        }
```

in AppDelegate

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 way:

1. using Package

First Install this library `yarn add react-device-detect`

Next, use it:

```js
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";

const DeviceDetector = () => (
  <div>I am rendered on: {isMobile ? "Mobile" : "Desktop"}</div>
);

export default DeviceDetector;
```

2. without Package

detect whether your app is rendering on mobile or desktop, like Navigator.maxTouchPoints.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const DeviceDetector = () => {
  const [deviceType, setDeviceType] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let hasTouchScreen = false;
    if ("maxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
      hasTouchScreen = navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
    } else if ("msMaxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
      hasTouchScreen = navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;
    } else {
      const mQ = window.matchMedia && matchMedia("(pointer:coarse)");
      if (mQ && mQ.media === "(pointer:coarse)") {
        hasTouchScreen = !!mQ.matches;
      } else if ("orientation" in window) {
        hasTouchScreen = true; // deprecated, but good fallback
      } else {
        // Only as a last resort, fall back to user agent sniffing
        var UA = navigator.userAgent;
        hasTouchScreen =
          /\b(BlackBerry|webOS|iPhone|IEMobile)\b/i.test(UA) ||
          /\b(Android|Windows Phone|iPad|iPod)\b/i.test(UA);
      }
    }
    if (hasTouchScreen) {
      setDeviceType("Mobile");
    } else {
      setDeviceType("Desktop");
    }
  }, []);

  return <div>I am rendered on: {deviceType}</div>;
};

export default DeviceDetector;
```